# NoMatch for react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying the handle the situation that the user is writing a path that doesn't exist. for example- if the user clicks on `Will Not Match` link, well, the `NoMatch` component renders as expected.

However, if the user goes the url, and changes it to "/abcd", a GET request is sent to server and an error returns, so there's no use of the react router. How can I make it so that `NoMatch` component will be rendered in this case as well?

I'm using react-router v4, BTW.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
      <div>
          <h3>No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code></h3>
      </div>
    )

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
          <Router>
              <div>
                  <Link to="/page1">page1</Link>
                  <Link to="/page2">page2</Link>
                  <Link to="/will/not/match">Will Not Match</Link>

                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/page1" component={page1}/>
                    <Route path="/page2" component={page2}/>
                    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
                  </Switch>
              </div>
          </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually need to deal with manual url writting on the server side. There is no way (at least not that I know of) to deal with this on the browser side.

So basically the idea is, on the server side, to always return your app whatever the called url (modulo some special routes for your api or whatever)

So when your user requests `/abc`

- the server will return the app (eg. the `index.html`);
- your browser will load the JS app;
- the router will read the URL;
- the `NoMatch` component will be shown.